# How to open first row by default while implementing accordion on an array of data using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I need one help. I have implemented accordion like feature on array of data using Angular.js. Here I need to open the first row by default first. I am explaining my code below.

> index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="firstCotroller">
    <div class="panel-group accordion-content-div" id="accordion" style="width:100%; margin:0px auto;" >
      <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="place in data">
        <div class="panel-heading active" role="tab" ng-click="manageCollapseExpand(place, false)">
          <a class="panel-title sky-blue-light" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent=""  aria-expanded="true">
              <i ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': place.expanded, 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !place.expanded }"></i> {{place.parentdes}} 
           </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">

          <div class="panel-body" ng-show="place.expanded">


            <!-- inner accordion starts here -->

            <div class="panel-group accordion-content-div accordioninner"  style="margin:0 auto 10px auto;">
              <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="cdes in place.childdes">
                <div class="panel-heading active panel-heading-sub-width" role="tab" style="border:1px solid #66afe9;" ng-click="manageCollapseExpand(cdes, true)">
                  <a class="collapsed panel-title sky-blue-light" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="" aria-expanded="true" style="border-bottom:none;">
                      <i ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': cdes.expanded, 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !cdes.expanded }"></i>{{cdes.des}}                       
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div id="inner1collapsea-5-1" class="" ng-show="cdes.expanded">
                  <div class="panel-body padding0" style="border-top:none;" ng-repeat="cd in cdes.subchilddes">

                    <!-- inner inner accordion -->

                    <div class="panel-group accordion-content-div accordioninner accordioninner-inner">
                      <div class="panel panel-default" style="border:1px solid #66afe9;">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                          <a class="panel-title sky-blue-light auditformpopup" role="button" ng-click="getAllNextPreviousIds(cd.sub_sub_id,$index,$parent.$index,$parent.$parent.$index)">
                          {{cd.des}}

                          </a>
                        </div>

                      </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- inner inner accordion end -->

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <!-- inner accordion end -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('firstCotroller',function($scope){
  $scope.data = [{
    "parentdes": "Parent description1",
    "parentid":"1",
    "childdes": [{
      "des": 'chile description11',
      "childid":"11",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des111',
        "sub_sub_id":"111"
      }]
    }, {
      "des": 'chile description12',
      "childid":"12",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des112',
        "sub_sub_id":"112"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "parentdes": "Parent description2",
    "parentid":"2",
    "childdes": [{
      "des": 'chile description21',
      "childid":"21",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des212',
        "sub_sub_id":"212"
      }]
    }, {
      "des": 'chile description22',
      "childid":"22",
      "subchilddes": [{
        "des": 'subchild des222',
        "sub_sub_id":"222"
      }]
    }]
  }];
  $scope.expandedParent = null;
  $scope.expandedChild = null;

  $scope.manageCollapseExpand = function(obj, isCity) {
    obj.expanded = !obj.expanded;
    if (obj !== $scope.expandedParent && obj !== $scope.expandedChild && obj.expanded) {
      $scope.collapseExpanded(isCity);
    }
    if (obj.expanded) {
      if (isCity) {
        $scope.expandedChild = obj;
      } else {
        $scope.expandedParent = obj;
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.collapseExpanded = function(clickedOnCity) {
    if (!clickedOnCity && $scope.expandedParent !== null) {
      $scope.expandedParent.expanded = false;
    }
    if ($scope.expandedChild !== null) {
      $scope.expandedChild.expanded = false;
    }
  }
})
```

How to open the first array of data by default so that it will work as per it is working right now? [Here is my full plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/xyPzBqeGRaC3qNGAgciw?p=preview). Please help me to do this.

Comment: search in ng-start in ng-repeat

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón : Little bit confused, Can you write your idea ?

Comment: He meant `ng-repeat-start="d in some_data"` and `ng-repeat-end`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey : I think this can not be implemented here as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix to your issue: because your visibility logic revolves around your `place.expanded` property we can utilize ng-init and invoke a function that sets that particular property for us:

> index.html:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="place in data"  ng-init="expandFirst(data)">
    //...
</div>
```

> script.js:

```
$scope.expandFirst = function(array)
{
    //something like this
    array[0].expanded = true;
    $scope.expandedParent = array[0];
}
```

And here's the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tfodiGBvgmMW92YCgNAX?p=preview)

Comment: But again one issue with this solution. ok by default first is open but when user is clicking on second the first one should close but its not happening like that.

Comment: @subhra I edited the answer and plunker code above to correct the issue you mentioned.